# Trace movement with data having time stamp in R

Tags: r

I want to create a contour plot in R with data having time stamp to trace movements across latitude, longitude and altitude. The data looks like this

```
TimeStamp LatitudeDegrees LongitudeDegrees AltitudeMeters
1   10:46:58              NA               NA             NA
2   10:47:05              NA               NA             NA
3   10:47:06              NA               NA             NA
4   10:47:07              NA               NA             NA
5   10:47:08              NA               NA             NA
6   10:47:10        37.35971        -6.572561          163.2
7   10:47:12        37.35971        -6.572561          163.2
8   10:47:13        37.35971        -6.572561          163.2
9   10:47:14        37.35971        -6.572560          163.2
10  10:47:15        37.35971        -6.572560          163.2
11  10:47:16        37.35971        -6.572560          163.2
12  10:47:17        37.35971        -6.572560          163.2
13  10:47:18        37.35971        -6.572560          163.2
14  10:47:19        37.35971        -6.572559          163.2
15  10:47:20        37.35971        -6.572559          163.2
16  10:47:21        37.35971        -6.572559          163.2
```

How can I achieve this in R?

Comment: The data that I see will just draw a path in 3D, or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes. The data will just draw a path in 3D.

Comment: You can plot these kind of data in many ways. Using [ggplot2](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_path.html) is one of them.